# In Excel how can I update an external file if it has so many rows that it cannot be loaded?

Tags: excel

I have a .csv file that has around 2 million rows, and I want to add a new column. Problem is, I could manage to that by losing a lot of data (basicly everything above ~1,1m rows). When I used connection to the external file (so that I could read all rows), and made changes to it in Power Query, the changes was not saved to the .csv file.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using a different tool for this. This is a straightforward exercise in most programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply one of several solutions:

1. Using a text editor which can handle huge files, save the csv files into smaller chunks. Apply the modifications to each chunk. Join chunks again to get the desired file.
2. Create a "small" program yourself, which loads the csv line by line and applies the modification, adding the resulting data to a second file.
3. Maybe some other software can handle that size of a csv. Patch the LibreOffice for this purpose, to handle 2000000+ lines - the source code is available :)